Mule 4 Facebook Authorization Code Grant Type
I'm developing a POC for a MuleSoft API (still running locally) that would fetch leads from a form. I have created a page and form and submitted a test lead via the Leads Ad Testing Tool. I can see the test lead in the Lead Centre.
I have also created the app with Product (Facebook Login for Business), I'm not sure if this is the same as "Facebook Login" I'm seeing in other post but there are no other option for a Facebook Login.
Below are the settings in the Basic > Settings and Client OAuth settings in the Facebook Login for Business > Settings menu.
[Basic > Settings] (https://i.sstatic.net/JBs5NK2C.png)
Client OAuth settings
Below is the XML Code with Request Config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:oauth="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth/current/mule-oauth.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration_client_credentials" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="b4a82eca-5bb9-4333-a8ea-7599b9307a51" >
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="graph.facebook.com">
            <http:authentication >
                <oauth:client-credentials-grant-type clientId="xxxx" clientSecret="xxxx" scopes="public_profile,email,pages_show_list,pages_read_engagement,pages_manage_metadata,leads_retrieval" tokenUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/oauth/access_token" />
            </http:authentication>
        </http:request-connection>
    </http:request-config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration1" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="826fbda6-7cf0-49b6-a153-6467b9f190c3" >
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="graph.facebook.com" >
            <http:authentication >
                <oauth:authorization-code-grant-type externalCallbackUrl="http://localhost:8081/oauth2callback" localAuthorizationUrl="http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize" authorizationUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize" clientId="xxxx" clientSecret="xxxx" scopes="public_profile,email,pages_show_list,pages_read_engagement,pages_manage_metadata,leads_retrieval" tokenUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/oauth/access_token" localCallbackConfig="asg-facebook-poc-api-httpListenerConfig" localCallbackConfigPath="/oauth2callback"/>
            </http:authentication>
        </http:request-connection>
    </http:request-config>
    
    <sub-flow name="fetch-leads-subflow" doc:id="b497fa90-1bcb-4321-a419-8311eb69fdbd" >
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" doc:id="c84c143f-1dc1-47f3-868a-8dc7d7685d98" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration1" path="/v20.0/me"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="6419b680-f8fd-44db-9305-00cea610913b" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="b8e4609e-12a2-4f2b-9600-f6fee13736a8" message="#[payload]"/>
    </sub-flow>
</mule>

Error I receive, when I tried accessing the simple endpoint in Facebook /me:
ERROR
ERROR 2024-09-25 20:48:13,112 [[MuleRuntime].uber.07: [asg-facebook-poc-api].get:\fetch-leads:asg-facebook-poc-api-config.CPU_LITE @5d699551] [processor: fetch-leads-subflow/processors/0; event: 69e982e0-7b3c-11ef-8d30-9009df41381d] org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.exception.DefaultExceptionListener: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : No access token found. Verify that you have authenticated before trying to execute an operation to the API.
Element               : fetch-leads-subflow/processors/0 @ asg-facebook-poc-api:scheduler-fetch-leads.xml:85 (Request)
Element DSL           : <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" doc:id="c84c143f-1dc1-47f3-868a-8dc7d7685d98" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration1" path="/v20.0/me"></http:request>
Error type            : HTTP:SECURITY
FlowStack             : at fetch-leads-subflow(fetch-leads-subflow/processors/0 @ asg-facebook-poc-api:scheduler-fetch-leads.xml:85 (Request))
at get:\fetch-leads:asg-facebook-poc-api-config(get:\fetch-leads:asg-facebook-poc-api-config/processors/1 @ asg-facebook-poc-api:asg-facebook-poc-api.xml:202 (fetch-leads-subflow))
at asg-facebook-poc-api-main(asg-facebook-poc-api-main/processors/0 @ asg-facebook-poc-api:asg-facebook-poc-api.xml:13)

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************


I also tried in Postman using http://localhost:8081/oauth/authorize, logged in and it worked.
I tried the other option client credentials grant type but it requires the access token which I don't have in the first place. Did not work on this.

Please do not use images for configurations, code or logs. Use [edit] to add the information to the question. For Mule applications copy the XML as text in your question. Also use [code block] formatting for those text blocks, including the logs you already added. It is always a good idea to read [ask] and [mre] to understand how to make good questions here. You should add the actual HTTP Request operation too.

Thank you @aled, added the details you mentioned.

It appears that you have just exposed your app secret in the above XML, so the first thing you should go and do now, is reset the app secret in your app dashboard.

"I also tried in Postman, I see this screen whenever I request a new token via Authorization" - yes, and? Are you not aware how OAuth works, and that this part has to happen inside the user's browser?

@C3roe, thanks! just changed it. Edited the question and got it working in Postman. However, still not working in the Mule API.
